# ElasticSearch : how to filter and change an index with an array field to a boolean field?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, filter, preconditions

I am using ElasticSearch 8.6.

Here below is my index :

1st Example

```
_source" : {
          "fieldA" : "M",
          "fieldB" : "SHOWER PACK",
          "fieldC" : "false",
          "fieldD" : "01",
          "fieldE" : "true",
          "fieldArrayA" : [ "val1","val2", "val3"]
}
```

I would like to query my index and get something like

```
IF fieldArrayA.length > 0 and val1 in fieldArrayA, THEN true ELSE false
```

So I would like to know it were possible to request my index to get the following result:

```
_source" : {
          "fieldA" : "M",
          "fieldB" : "SHOWER PACK",
          "fieldC" : "false",
          "fieldD" : "01",
          "fieldE" : "true",
          "fieldArrayA_as_boolean" : true
}
```

what would be the ElasticSearch query ?

2nd Example:

```
POST tly-idx_test1/_doc
{
  "fieldA": "M",
  "fieldB": "SHOWER PACK",
  "fieldC": "false",
  "fieldD": "01",
  "fieldE": "true",
  "fieldArrayA": [
    "val1",
    "val2",
    "val3"
  ],
   "fieldArrayB": [
    {"fieldB1":"val1"},
    {"fieldB1":"val2"},
    {"fieldB1":"val3"}
  ]
}
```

The mapping is the following :

```
PUT tly-idx_test1
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fieldA": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldArrayA": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
     "fieldArrayB": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "fieldB1": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "text": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          }
        }
     },
      "fieldB": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldC": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldD": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldE": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to get the following results with

```
 IF fieldArrayB.length > 0 and val1 in fieldArrayB, THEN true ELSE false
```

?

```
  _source" : {
              "fieldA" : "M",
              "fieldB" : "SHOWER PACK",
              "fieldC" : "false",
              "fieldD" : "01",
              "fieldE" : "true",
              "fieldArrayB_as_boolean" : true
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-fields.html#script-fields).

What you want is only possible via script using Elasticsearch. However scripts are not recommended as they are not performant.
The other option is to make a query with Terms Query, but you don't have the field you want the "fieldArrayA_as_boolean".

Still you can receive the results of the Terms Query and in your application create a logic to add this field in your answer, which would be better thinking in the long term.

Indexing:

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fieldA": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldArrayA": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "fieldB": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldC": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldD": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fieldE": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_doc
{
  "fieldA": "M",
  "fieldB": "SHOWER PACK",
  "fieldC": "false",
  "fieldD": "01",
  "fieldE": "true",
  "fieldArrayA": [
    "val1",
    "val2",
    "val3"
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": "*",
  "script_fields": {
    "fieldArrayA_as_boolean": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
              def list = doc['fieldArrayA'];
              return list.size() > 0 && list.contains('val1');
              """
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
              def list = doc['fieldArrayA'];
              return list.size() > 0 && list.contains('val1');
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Example with [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "fieldArrayA.keyword": [
        "val1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try but I can not make it work. Should the array field be a keyword type instead of a nested one ?

Comment: According to the document you provided, the list must be of the keyword type, it is not necessary to work with nested.  if you change to keyword you can replace in the query "fieldArrayA.keyword" for "fieldArrayA"

Comment: It is pretty weird : the script works in that way `"script": {
        "source": """
              def list = doc['fieldArrayA.field1'];
              return list.size() >= 0 ;
              """
      }` If try to increase the list size 0 to 1, it does not work anymore. It as if the operator is not understood ?

Comment: I have made different tests with [link]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-walkthrough.html But it is as the lenght or size function does not count

Comment: why field1 in doc['fieldArrayA.field1']? try this: """def list = doc['fieldArrayA'];return list.size() >= 0 ;""" . I added my example in answer.

Comment: Yes,  Thank you, your example works !!! in fact, my real need is when I have an array like that : `" "fieldArrayA": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "field1": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "fields": {
                "text": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "depot_analyzer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `  It is possible when the keyword is inside a nested field ?

Comment: provide a document with fieldArrayA and field1 property

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question with the 2nd example. A big thanks !

Comment: I am still testing ... It is really possible to solve the 2nd exemple?

Comment: i was searching about nested and script but I think doesn`t have support. Look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-fields-api.html)